# Magento 2.2 Observer not working

Tags: php, magento, magento2.2

Here are my codes. When I tried to save product `newfile123456789.txt` file is not updated.

**Codes of events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after">
        <observer name="Company_Module_Product_Save_After" instance="Company\Module\Observer\productSaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Codes of ProductSaveAfter.php**

```
namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class productSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //$_product = $observer->getProduct(); // you will get product object
        //$_sku     = $_product->getSku(); // for sku

        $myfile = fopen("newfile123456789.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = "John Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);

        die('Observer Is called!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define product save event as given below:-

> ```
> <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
>     <observer name="Company_Module_Product_Save_After" instance="YCompany\Module\Observer\productSaveAfter" />
> </event>
> ```

Also please make sure that  your observer is working and folder in which file is created has write permission.